# Multiprocessing in Python with time offset

Tags: python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I have a code in which there are two functions (`fun(), fun2()`). Now I want to execute these 2 functions simultaneously but with some time offset. 
Note: The execution time of fun1() and fun2() is the same.

**Explanation**:

1. The code is running.
2. **fun1()** is running and doing some tasks.
3. After a particular time offset (say after 10 seconds) I want to run
   **fun2()** along with **fun1()**.
4. When **fun1()** is done it should stop (Here **fun2()** is still running).
5. Again after 10 seconds **fun1()** should run and when **fun2()** is done it should stop (Here **fun1()** is still running).
6. And this process should repeat.

For parallel execution, I tried Multiprocess in python.
Below is a sample code.

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from datetime import datetime



def fun1():
   #do something

def fun2():
   #do something

main():
t = 0 # initially time = 0
t_offset = 10 # time offset

processes = []

p1 = Process(target=fun1)   # Process p1 for fun1
p2 = Process(target=fun2)   # Process p2 for fun2

processes.append(p1)
processes.append(p2)


while True:
    dt = datetime.now()   
    t = datetime.now().second

    if(dt.second == 0):  # Here process p1 is started at beginning of a minute.
        p1.start()

    if(t == t_offset)    # Here after 10 seconds offset process should start.
        p2.start()
```

Is there any solution to the above problem. Can I have two processes running together with time offset between them?

Answer (score 0):

Just add a time delay to the process you want by adding some lines of code at it's start.

eg.

```
import time
n=0
while n<3000:
    time.sleep(1)
    n=n+1
    print(str(3000-n)  + 'until process ')
else:
    pass
```

causes delay of 300 seconds before body of process starts.